# Invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator<<’

Tags: c++, arrays

**I was trying to sum two arrays into a third one!!**

```
int main()
{
   int RoadHeights[2000] , TopoHeights[2000] , Differences[4000] , i , n ;

   cout << "Enter the number of stations! " << endl;
   cin >> n;

   cout << "Enter the heights of stations on Road! " << endl;

   for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
      cin >> RoadHeights[i];

   cout << "Enter the heights of stations on Ground! " << endl;

   for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
      cin >> TopoHeights[i];

   cout << "Height differences are: " << endl;

   for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
      cout << Differences [4000] = RoadHeights[i] - TopoHeights[i] << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The error is in the last line!! I I cant't get the third array when I run the program.

Comment: 2  things: `Differences[4000]` is out of bounds, and the `=` operator has [lower precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `<<` operator, so wrap up your expression with parentheses

Comment: Why is the size of `Differences` 4000? If you want to store them, you just need 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things: Differences[4000] is out of bounds, and the = operator has [lower precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the << operator, so wrap up your expression with parentheses:

```
cout << (Differences [i] = RoadHeights[i] - TopoHeights[i]) << endl;
```

Otherwise, `cout << Differences[i]` is evaluated first, returning an `ostream&`, effectively becoming

```
cout << Differences[i]; 
cout = (RoadHeights[i] - TopoHeights[i]) << endl;
```

Clearly the second line is an error

This will solve your compiler problem, but I'm guessing you have more logic problems in there. For example, Hardcoded array sizes, but user input for the size afterwards? What if `n` is `5000`? Try using a `std::vector` instead.

```
std::vector<int> RoadHeights, TopoHeights, Differences;
int i , n ;

cout << "Enter the number of stations! " << endl;
cin >> n;
RoadHeights.resize(n);
TopoHeights.resize(n);
Differences.resize(n);
// proceed as normal
```

Comment: :O Worked like a charm!! Thank you, man> :) About the 4000 ... I was just trying to solve it :D Didn't know what to do. the parentheses solved the problem. ;)